# Heroku returning Postgres error on active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activeadmin

I deployed my App to Heroku. When I want to View a record, it returns an error:

```
2012-07-13T22:28:04+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin/non_profits/1" for 200.40.55.210 at 2012-07-13 22:28:04 +0000
2012-07-13T22:28:06+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
2012-07-13T22:28:06+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...Profit' AND "active_admin_comments"."resource_id" = 1 AND "a...
2012-07-13T22:28:06+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any hints?

Comment: Are you using Postgres for your dev db?

Answer (score 0):

Yea, I would suggest changing your dev db over to PG. Heroku strongly recommends doing this if you're on their Cedar stack https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3.

This should help you replicate the issue in development.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. It is not possible right now but isn't that a incompatibility issue from active admin?

Comment: I'm not sure. It was just my first thought as to why you would get that error in production and not in dev. But I could be wrong.